# How to set up Sublime text 3 to run and compile java on linux?

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, sublimetext3

Recently I've decided to learn Java and give it a try. I have a short and amateur experience with python, therefore I'm not a kind of programming expert. After many days trying to figure out how to set up Sublime Text to run and compile Java, I've decided to come for any help. 
I've already installed JDK and I was using Netbeans, but I prefer a minimalistic IDE. 
I created a .sublime-build file like this below..
[image: Java sublime.build]

However when I try to build the code, it returns me that error below..
[image: Java Error]

So, probably I've done something wrong, but I can't really figure out what it is. I'm using Ubuntu 14.10 and that's the reason I cannot find many answers out there, so I'd really appreciate if anyone could help me out!

Comment: Did you put the `run-java.sh` script in the `~/bin` directory? Did you `chmod +x` it to make it executable? BTW, your Java program is missing a semicolon.

Comment: yeah, I noticed, but it was made after the error returned.. a moment of anger probably lol
But I'm not quite sure I've put the run-java.sh script in the ~/bin directory and I didn't chmod +x . I'm new in the world of programming, so forgive me for my lack of knowledge. How could I do that?

Comment: Well, look in /home/priscilla/bin. Is run-java.sh there? If not, copy it there. To make it executable, type `chmod +x run-java.sh` in that directory.

Answer (score 11):

Tested on **Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with Sublime Text3.**
Make your own **sublime-build** system, and enter this code:

```
{
   "shell_cmd": "javac \"$file\" && java \"$file_base_name\"",
   "file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
   "selector": "source.java",
}
```

This will let you first compile the file AND run the class based on the file name together. After this, you will see the result of string "Hello World"

[image: Result]

Answer (score 5):

Look at https://gist.github.com/jfcalvo/3789664
their solution is

```
JavaC.sublime-build
{
  "cmd": ["javac \"$file_name\" && java \"$file_base_name\""],
  "shell": true,
  "file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
  "selector": "source.java"
}
```

much like J. Seo, and Mad Physicist above, only with "shell":true added.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create two files in the directory of your source file:

   - `input.txt` - It is for giving user inputs.
   - `output.txt` - It is for storing the outputs(you can use the built-in terminal as well).
2. Go to *Tools* > *Build System* > *New Build System*.
   Now, write the following code and save it as a new `.sublime-build` file.
   [customJava.sublime-build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WdEPl.png)
3. Now, select the new build system, provide inputs(if required) and run the code.(Ctr+B)

Answer (score 1):

Use this build.

```
{
  "shell_cmd": "javac -Xlint  \"${file}\"",
  "file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
  "working_dir": "${file_path}",
  "selector": "source.java",

   "variants": [

  { "shell_cmd":"javac -Xlint  \"${file}\" && java $file_base_name  < input.txt > output.txt",
  "name": "Run"
  }
 ]
 }
```

Save this sublime build and run the program with `ctrl + shift + B` with run variant. Without run variant it will just create `.class` file but wont run it.

This build will read the input from `input.txt` and print the output in `output.txt`.

Note: Both `input.txt` and `output.txt` must be present in the same working directory as your `.java` file.