# SublimeText 3 compile java custom build with Errors

Tags: java, build, sublimetext3, sublimetext

As per the title i am trying to create a build for Sublime Text 3 to compile all .java files in /home/DND (including sub directories), and then display the errors in the code blocks as per the normal compiler does.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28416885/how-to-set-up-sublime-text-3-to-run-and-compile-java-on-linux) will surely help you.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't as im not looking to run the program just compile it and display errors. Thanks though