# How to make Sublime Text 3 compile and run java through terminal on Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, sublimetext3

I am trying to create a Sublime Text 3 build system to compile and run my java code through the terminal on Ubuntu, not the built in window in the bottom of the Sublime window which i circled in red. [image]
The current build system I'm using is this:

```
{
   "shell_cmd": "javac \"$file\" && java \"$file_base_name\"",
   "file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
   "selector": "source.java",
}
```

Which works, just it doesn't open it in the terminal like i want it to. On my windows machine I use this:

```
{
"cmd": ["javac", "$file_name","&&","start","cmd","/k","java", "$file_base_name"],
"path":"C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-11.0.3\\bin",
"shell": true
}
```

Which does run it in cmd, just obviously on windows not linux

This question is very similar to the following:
[How to set up Sublime text 3 to run and compile java on linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28416885/how-to-set-up-sublime-text-3-to-run-and-compile-java-on-linux) which is where i got the current build system, just they wanted it to run in sublime not terminal

Answer (score 1):

Here is my code for sublime in ubuntu which will popup gnome-terminal and then will execute the code there.

```
{
  "cmd": ["javac", "$file"],
  "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
  "working_dir": "${file_path}",
  "selector": "source.java",
  "variants":
  [
      {
          "name": "Run",
          "shell": true,
          "cmd": ["gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c \"java ${file_base_name};tput dim;tput setaf 6; echo; echo -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ;tput sgr0;tput setaf 6;echo;echo  Done Shivam   now Press ENTER to continue; read line;exit; exec bash;\"'"]
      }
  ]    
}
```

Comment: its working!! but we have to first compile using MyJava build and then use MyJava-run, is there any way we can do it in one build only.